# How to clone a contact?

Tags: contacts

Just hit a few cases where it would be great to have a contact with exact same status eg event, member, relationship, contribution, and of course custom fields on contact and those other entities etc so we can 'test' a fix on.

Might not need to clone 'everything' eg Activities, since I can see complexity bursting forth.

Anyone else looked at doing this? Any thoughts about (im)possibility of doing this?

Answer (score 3):

You can do a shallow clone with `cv` (and a little stripping of the original ID).

```
cv api Contact.getsingle id=203 | sed -e 's#"id"#"foo"#g' | sed -e 's#"contact_id"#"bar"#g' | cv api Contact.create --in=json
```

For the rest, you'd really need to specify the outcomes. Should the spouse be a clone too, or the original? The event registrations are for a cloned event or the original? The employer and other relationships?

1980s movie hijinks will abound as you explore the philosophical implications of cloning, in a time before it was a hellish near-reality.

---

OK, it's sprint, here's some JS to clone a contact:

```
// Go find a contact
CRM.api3('Contact', 'get', {
  "sequential": 1,
  "id": 361
}).done(function(res_old) {
  // Grab contact out and remove their ID.
  var contact_params = res_old.values[0];
  // Remove existing ID so we create a new contact.
  delete contact_params.id;
  delete contact_params.contact_id;
  // Create our new contact.
  CRM.api3('Contact', 'create', contact_params);
});
```

And, to clone a contact and related contributions:

```
// Cloning a full contact + related contributions (+ ...)
CRM.api3('Contact', 'get', {
  "sequential": 1,
  "id": 361
}).done(function(res_old) {
  // Grab contact out and remove their ID.
  var contact_params = res_old.values[0];
  // Remove existing ID so we create a new contact.
  delete contact_params.id;
  delete contact_params.contact_id;
  // Create our new contact.
  CRM.api3('Contact', 'create', contact_params)
    .done(function (res_new) {
      // Now handle related entities, one by one.
      // Contributions only as an example below.
      CRM.api3('Contribution', 'get', {contact_id: res_old.id})
        .done(function(res_contrib) {
          for (var key in res_contrib.values) {
            var new_contrib = res_contrib.values[key];
            // Returned values need to be adjusted so we create a new contribution.
            // Remove link(s) with previous contribution.
            delete new_contrib.id;
            delete new_contrib.contribution_id;
            // Associate with the new contact.
            new_contrib.contact_id = res_new.id;
            // Contribution.create requires financial_type_id, not provided by
            // Contribution.get. That's a whole other topic. Random ID here.
            // You'd actually need to use api "return" to get all fields.
            new_contrib.financial_type_id = 1;
            CRM.api3('Contribution', 'create', new_contrib)
              .done(function (res_newcontrib) {
                // console.log(res_newcontrib, 'rnc');
              }); //
          }
        });
        // Repeat as above for other related entities you wish to clone.
    });
});
```

And so on to clone Contact with related Participant, Contribution & Relationship records ... Some thoughts on this:

- Cloning a contact or other simple entity is straightforward here.
- Cloning related entities got verbose fast!
- It's kinda weird that you have to remove both contribution.contribution_id and contribution.id, both contact.id and contact.contact_id ...
- It's also kinda weird that you can't pipe a `contribution.get` back into a `contribution.create` because `contribution.get` does not return the (required) `financial_type_id` field.
- Sounds like to handle this last point, the current approach would require using `return` with the API to specify all the fields on an entity, including the required ones not returned by default.

Comment: in the scenario i was thinking around, the Contact and any Participant, Contribution, Relationship records would be cloned. I was not requiring or even considering cloning spouses or Events.

Answer (score 2):

You can clone by creating a new contact and merging with the old one.

Once merged you can pull the old one back by searching in deleted contacts and restoring the deleted one.

Comment: hmm. interesting concept. i will give it a try

Comment: This is quite hacky but it quite works!
But that way you can copy only the basic contact information. Things like event registrations or contributions are all only in 1 contact (they was moved (not copied) form one to the other).

Answer (score 1):

Interesting idea Pete! Not looking at doing this. I would certainly limit to basic contact data and custom fields on contact level as a start. Perhaps relationships would make sense but hard to determine if they all need cloning (for example case relationships probably not)....

Comment: Yep, my sense is the interdependency of CiviCRM entities would mean you'd need to specify what should happen with each related civi-thing your contact is connected to. The API calls will be the easy part!

Comment: Paul B wants to know [How to clone a contribution?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/18394/copy-duplicate-a-contribution) - maybe there's demand for an entity clone tool.

Comment: Excellent. Clone me a Burgess when you have it up and running ;-)